# Keep Apple Watch awake

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm building an Apple Watch app which is controlled using motion. Right now, I'm looking for a way to keep the app awake without the user interacting with the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't keep Apple Watch awake programmatically. You can change the end-user settings in Apple Watch settings app or in the Apple Watch app on iPhone, but there is no way to do this programmatically and with coding.

The screen will be turned off after a certain amount of time (which is adjustable in Apple Watch Settings app, or in the Apple Watch app on iPhone), or when user lowers his or her wrist. You can't do anything in order to stop this, because it is one of the main and core features of the Apple Watch, which is the same thing in all apps ever made for it.

Answer (score 5):

As for now that is not possible. The watch will lock when the user is lowering his/hers wrist or after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Beta 5 has an option in settings to keep the display awake for 70 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I used (Version : 7.1)

- First : AppleWatch "General" -> "Wake screen" -> "wake for 70 seconds"
- Second :set the value of  **isAutorotating** true

now I can rotate my watch without falling in background.

Link ; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/2868464-isautorotating